How would I prove or disprove this statement?
The question is to prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the differential equation $\prod_{i=0}^{n}{y^{(i)}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{y^{(i)}}$ has a solution (not including $y=0$) with a domain of $\Bbb{R}$  or disprove the following statement and determine the smallest n such that the statement is false. (Also note there is no initial value).
I first tried $n=0$ and got $y^{0}=y^{0}$ which has infinite solutions and hence $n=0$ works. Then I tried n=1 which is $y^{(1)}y^{(0)}=y^{(1)}+y^{(0)}$ which has solution $y=-W(-Ae^{-x})$ ( note: $W(x)$ is the inverse function of $y=xe^{x}$).
I believe $-W(-Ae^{-x})$ is a valid solution since the function is well defined for any real value of $x$.
I also realized induction wouldn't work since the solutions for $y$ change dependent on the value of $n$. After that i got stuck on the problem.
So i was wondering if there was a theorem or technique to prove this or to find an $n$ to disprove the statement.

I'm sure many will find the underlying math question interesting. But, it behooves me to make sure that you study our abridged guide to new askers. Basically, you need to do something to convince others that you are not simply dumping your homework here. Not saying that this would look, walk and talk like a homework problem. The rule is the same nevertheless.

Sorry if this looked like a homework problem. I saw this problem on an online textbook I'm reading to prepare for my differential equations class I have next semester but unfortunately the version I have doesn't have any solution.

@NFlinn: In that case, you should edit your question and add your thoughts and/or attempts on the problem. What about the small cases? Did you try those?

Thx for the advice, I will edit now.

What would constitute a solution in this case? Do you expect a function with domain $\Bbb{R}? Would some non-trivial interval do? Is there any kind of initial value attached to the problem?

I forgot to add that and will be doing so in the edit but the domain is expected to be $\Bbb{R}$ and there is no initial value to this problem.

There is nothing that prevents this equation or its explicit form
$$
y^{(n)}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y^{(k)}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}y^{(k)}-1}
$$
from having a local, unique and analytic solution. Obviously the domain of this ODE has to exclude the hypersurface of roots of the denominator.
It is doubtful that any symbolic solution exists for $n>3$, but that is true for almost any differential equation outside of textbooks.
